# Check for letter(s) in array with numbers

Tags: java, arrays, numbers

Been stuck awhile trying to figure out a way to check for letters inside an array. In the array are 1s and 0s like so

`[0000000000001000000000000, 0000000000010100000000000, 0000000000100010000000000, 0000000001000001000000000, 0000000010000000100000000, 0000000100000000010000000]`

Using a for loop to scan for possible letters in the array how can I check for letters?

```
for (int j = 0; j < lineCount; j++) {
        if (array[j].matches("^a-zA-Z+$")) {

            System.out.println("Not a number found");
            System.exit(1);
        }
```

Comment: Please read how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask It would help to have more details. For example what is the datatype of array? Is it an array  of strings? If so then show your array example as an array of strings `["000111000", "11001110", etc.]`. Why is is that you think the regex "^a-zA-Z+$" checks for 1 and 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that these are strings of 0's and 1's why not just do

- `[10]*` match any 0 or more binary digits.
- the `!` negates the boolean result

```
if(!array[j].matches("[10]*")) {
    System.out.println("Not a number found");
    System.exit(1);
}
```

For any string of digits you could do:

- `.*[a-zA-Z].*` returns true if one letter exists anywhere in the
  string.

```
if (array[j].matches(".*[a-zA-Z].*")) {//check for a letter
        System.out.println("Not a number found");
        System.exit(1);
}
```